# ¿Cómo eliminar un contacto de una agenda con archivo?

Tags: c, archivo

Estoy haciendo una agenda como proyecto para aprender a programar en C, me basé en una agenda explicada por video pero el tutorial no está terminado, el autor no terminó y solo me falta la función de borrar un registro pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo.

Este es el código que llevo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct registro{
  int id;
  char cto_nom[80];
  char cto_tel[15];
};

struct registro *registros = NULL;
int total=0;
FILE *archivo = NULL;

void cargar();
void guardar();
void alta();
void ver();
void busqueda();
void eliminar();

int main() {
  int opcion;
  char temp[10];
  cargar();
  system("clear");
  do{
    printf("total de registros %i\n",total);
    printf("1. Agregar contacto.\n");
    printf("2. Ver contacto.\n");
    printf("3. Busqueda\n");
    printf("4. Eliminar contactos\n");
    printf("5. salir. \n");
    printf("Ingrese su opcion: ");
    fgets(temp,10,stdin);
    opcion = atoi(temp);
    switch (opcion) {
      case 1:
          printf("Usted selecciono %i\n",opcion );
          alta();
      break;
      case 2:
        printf("Usted selecciono %i\n",opcion );
        ver();
      break;
      case 3:
        busqueda();
      break;
      case 4:
        eliminar();
      break;
      dafault:
        printf("opcion incorrecta\n");
      break;
      }
    }while (opcion != 5);
    guardar();
    return 0;
}

void alta(){
  registros = realloc(registros,sizeof(struct registro)*(total+1));
  memset(&registros[total],0,sizeof(struct registro));
  printf("ingrese el nombre de registro %i: ",total+1 );
  fgets(registros[total].cto_nom,80,stdin);
  printf("ingrese el telefono del registo %i: ",total+1);
  fgets(registros[total].cto_tel,15,stdin);
  registros[total].id = total+1;
  total ++;
  system("clear");

}

void guardar(){
  archivo = fopen("agenda.txt","wb");
  if(archivo != NULL){
    fwrite(&total,sizeof(int),1,archivo);
    fwrite(registros,sizeof(struct registro),total,archivo);
    fclose(archivo);
  }else{
    printf("error de archivo");
  }
}

void cargar(){
  archivo = fopen("agenda.txt","rb");
  if(archivo != NULL){
    fread(&total,sizeof(int),1,archivo);
    registros = calloc(sizeof(struct registro),total);
    fread(registros,sizeof(struct registro),total,archivo);
    fclose(archivo);
  }else{
    printf("error de archivo");
  }
}

void ver(){
  system("clear");
  int numero = 0;
  char temp[10];
  do {
    printf("Numero de contactos menor o igual %i\n", total);
    printf("Que registro desea buscar: ");
    fgets(temp,10,stdin);
    numero = atoi(temp);
  } while(numero>total || numero<=0);
  numero --;
  printf("Registro numero %i\n", numero);
  printf("Nombre: %s\n",registros[numero].cto_nom);
  printf("Telefono: %s\n", registros[numero].cto_tel);
  printf("Presiona enter para continuar... \n");
  getchar();
  system("clear");
}

void busqueda(){
  system("clear");
  int opcion,i,index;
  bool encontrado,entrar;
  char temp[10];
  char buscar[80];
  do{
  encontrado = false;
  entrar = true;
  system("clear");
  printf("Como queire buscar? \n");
  printf("1. Por nombre.\n");
  printf("2. Por telefono\n");
  printf("3. Regrear al menu anterior.. \n");
  printf("Ingrese su opcion: ");
  fgets(temp,10,stdin);
  opcion = atoi(temp);
  switch (opcion) {
    case 1:
        printf("Ingrese el nombre: ");
        fgets(buscar,80,stdin);
        i=0;
        while(i < total && !encontrado){
            if(strcmp(buscar,registros[i].cto_nom) == 0){
              printf("Nombre encontrado\n");
              encontrado = true;
              entrar = false;
              index = i;
            }
            i++;
        }
    break;
    case 2:
      printf("Ingrese el telefono ");
      fgets(buscar,15,stdin);
      i=0;
      while(i < total && !encontrado){
          if(strcmp(buscar,registros[i].cto_tel) == 0){
            printf("telefono encontrado\n");
            encontrado = true;
            entrar = false;
            index = i;
          }
          i++;
      }
    break;
    case 3:
      entrar = false;
    break;
    dafault:
      printf("opcion incorrecta\n");
    break;
    }
  }while (entrar);
  if(encontrado){
      printf("Registro encontrado \n");
      printf("Registro numero %i\n", registros[index].id);
      printf("Nombre: %s\n",registros[index].cto_nom);
      printf("Telefono: %s\n", registros[index].cto_tel);
      printf("press enter....");
      getchar();
  }

}

void eliminar(){

}
```

¿Cómo puedo eliminar un registro de la agenda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la eliminación lo que se puede hacer, es marcar al registro que desear eliminar, marcarlo como inválido, por ejemplo se le podría asignar un -1.
Pero la eliminación hace que cuando guardes los registros, tengas que ir comprobando cual es válido y cual no, los inválidos los pasas por alto, y solo escribir cada registro válido.
Pero entre el borrado y el agregado si se utiliza el "total" como valor de id, puede suceder que los ids se repitan, por lo tanto una opción sería mantener un contador del siguiente id. Este id se guardaría también en el archivo.

Una buena opción también sería guardar también la versión de la agenda, en caso de que en un futuro quieras modificar los campos de la estructura "registro".

También he notado que usas muchas variables globales, te recomiendo que no abuses del uso de dichas variables, no es una buena práctica de programación, especialmente cuando los programas suelen crecer, el programa puede llegar a ser muy dificil de mantener, lo recomentable es unar una estructura para la agenda.

También tenías un error donde escribías "dafault" cuando es "default".

También en el nombre de archivo usas la extensión "txt", yo no lo aconsejaría, ya que da la impresión de ser un archivo de texto, cuando en realidad es en formato binario, pero esto te recomiendo inventarte una extensión o simplemente usar la típica extensión "bin".

Hice mi versión de la agenda, entre los cambiós que hice fue:
Implement la eliminación de contacto
Modificación del alta para reutilizar, registros eliminados
El guardar comprueba si el registro es valido, y también guarda versión de la agenda, y el siguiente id.
Agregé búsqueda por id
Agregé la opción de listar todo
Agregé la función leer_int() que facilita la lectura de un entero
Agregé la función leer_string() que facilita la lectura de un string (sin fin de línea)

Espero que te sirva

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#ifndef __cplusplus
#define true 1
#defie false 0
typedef int bool;
#endif
#else
#include <stdbool.h>
#endif

//
// Leer entero
//
int leer_int()
{
    char buf[10];
    fgets(buf, 10, stdin);
    return atoi(buf);
}
//
// Leer string
//
void leer_string(char* s, int max)
{
    char* p;

    // Obtener string
    fgets(s, max, stdin);

    // Eliminar fin de línea
    for(p = s; *p != '\0'; p++)
    {
        if(*p == '\n')
        {
            *p = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
}
//
// Limpiar pantalla
//
void clear_screen()
{
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    system("cls");      // Windows
#else
    system("clear");    // Unix/Linux
#endif
}
//
// Esperar hasta presionar enter
//
void esperar_enter()
{
    printf("\nPresiona enter para continuar... \n");
    while(getchar() != '\n')
    {
        // Nada
    }
}

#define NOMBRE_AGENDA           "agenda.bin"

//
// Agenda
//
struct agenda
{
    int version;                // Versión de la agenda
    int total;                  // Cantidad de registros en memoria (no necesariamente todos validos)
    int siguiente_id;           // Siguiente id al ingreser un nuevo
    struct registro* registros; // Array de registros
};
//
// Registro de agenda
//
struct registro
{
    int id;
    char cto_nom[80];
    char cto_tel[15];
};

//
// Nuevar agenda
//
void agenda_nueva(struct agenda* a)
{
    memset(a, 0, sizeof(struct agenda));
    a->version = 1;
    a->siguiente_id = 1;
}
//
// Cargar agenda
//
bool agenda_cargar(struct agenda* a)
{
    FILE* archivo = fopen(NOMBRE_AGENDA, "rb");
    if(archivo != NULL)
    {
        // Leer versión
        fread(&a->version, sizeof(int), 1, archivo);

        // Leer total de registros
        fread(&a->total, sizeof(int), 1, archivo);

        // Leer el siguiente id para un nuevo registro
        fread(&a->siguiente_id, sizeof(int), 1, archivo);

        // Leer registros
        a->registros = (registro*)calloc(sizeof(struct registro), a->total);
        fread(a->registros, sizeof(struct registro), a->total, archivo);

        // Cerrar archivo
        fclose(archivo);

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
//
// Guardar agenda
//
void agenda_guardar(struct agenda* a)
{
    FILE* archivo = fopen(NOMBRE_AGENDA,"wb");
    if(archivo != NULL)
    {
        //
        // Calcular total de registros válidos
        //
        int t = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < a->total; i++)
        {
            if(a->registros[i].id != -1) // ¿El id es válido?
                t++;
        }
        //
        // Guardar versión
        //
        fwrite(&a->version, sizeof(int), 1, archivo);

        //
        // Guardar total de registros válidos
        //
        fwrite(&t,sizeof(int),1,archivo);

        //
        // Guardar el siguiente id para registros
        //
        fwrite(&a->siguiente_id, sizeof(int), 1, archivo);

        //
        // Guardar todos los registros válidos
        //
        for(int i = 0; i < a->total; i++)
        {
            if(a->registros[i].id != -1) // ¿El id es válido?
                fwrite(&a->registros[i], sizeof(struct registro), 1, archivo); // Escribir
        }
        //
        // Cerrar archivo
        //
        fclose(archivo);

        //
        // Eliminar estructuras de la memoria
        //
        free(a->registros);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error de archivo");
    }
}
void agenda_alta(struct agenda* a)
{
    int index = -1;

    clear_screen();
    printf("Agregar contacto\n\n");

    //
    // Buscar un registro eliminado para rellenarlo con uno nuevo
    //
    for(int i = 0; i < a->total && index == -1; i++)
    {
        if(a->registros[i].id == -1)
            index = i;
    }
    //
    // Si no se encontro un registro vacío, agrandar el arreglo de registros
    //
    if(index == -1)
    {
        // El índice es el último del array
        index = a->total;
        // Incrementar el total
        a->total++;
        // Agrandar el arreglo
        a->registros = (registro*)realloc(a->registros,sizeof(struct registro) * (a->total));
    }
    //
    // Cargar datos de contacto
    //
    a->registros[index].id = a->siguiente_id;
    printf("Ingrese el nombre de registro %i: ", a->siguiente_id);
    leer_string(a->registros[index].cto_nom, 80);
    printf("Ingrese el telefono del registo %i: ", a->siguiente_id);
    leer_string(a->registros[index].cto_tel, 15);

    // Incrementar al siguiente id
    a->siguiente_id++;

    // ...
    printf("\nEl registro se ha ingresado correctamente\n");
    esperar_enter();
}

void agenda_ver(struct agenda* a)
{
    int index = 0;
    clear_screen();
    printf("Ver contacto\n\n");

    do
    {
        printf("Numero de contactos menor o igual %i\n", a->total);
        printf("Que registro desea buscar: ");
        index = leer_int();
    }
    while(index > a->total || index <= 0);
    index--;
    if(a->registros[index].id == -1)
    {
        printf("El contacto fue borrado\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Registro numero %i\n", index+1);
        printf("  Id: %d\n", a->registros[index].id);
        printf("  Nombre: %s\n", a->registros[index].cto_nom);
        printf("  Telefono: %s\n", a->registros[index].cto_tel);
    }
    esperar_enter();
}

void agenda_busqueda(struct agenda* a)
{
    int opcion,i,index;
    bool encontrado,entrar;
    int id;
    char buscar[80];
    do
    {
        encontrado = false;
        entrar = true;
        clear_screen();
        printf("Como quiere buscar? \n");
        printf("  0. Regrear al menu anterior.. \n");
        printf("  1. Por id.\n");
        printf("  2. Por nombre.\n");
        printf("  3. Por telefono\n");
        printf("Ingrese su opcion: ");
        opcion = leer_int();
        switch(opcion)
        {
            case 0:
                entrar = false;
                break;
            case 1:
                printf("Ingrese el id: ");
                id = leer_int();
                for(i = 0; i < a->total && !encontrado; i++)
                {
                    if(a->registros[i].id == id)
                    {
                        printf("Id encontrado\n");
                        encontrado = true;
                        entrar = false;
                        index = i;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Ingrese el nombre: ");
                leer_string(buscar, 80);
                for(i = 0; i < a->total && !encontrado; i++)
                {
                    if(strcmp(buscar, a->registros[i].cto_nom) == 0)
                    {
                        printf("Nombre encontrado\n");
                        encontrado = true;
                        entrar = false;
                        index = i;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Ingrese el telefono: ");
                leer_string(buscar, 15);
                for(i = 0; i < a->total && !encontrado; i++)
                {
                    if(strcmp(buscar, a->registros[i].cto_tel) == 0)
                    {
                        printf("telefono encontrado\n");
                        encontrado = true;
                        entrar = false;
                        index = i;
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                printf("opcion incorrecta\n");
                getchar();
                break;
        }
    }
    while(entrar);
    printf("\n");
    if(encontrado)
    {
        printf("Registro encontrado \n");
        printf("  Id %i\n", a->registros[index].id);
        printf("  Nombre: %s\n", a->registros[index].cto_nom);
        printf("  Telefono: %s\n", a->registros[index].cto_tel);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No se ha encontrado el contacto\n");
    }
    esperar_enter();
}
void agenda_eliminar(struct agenda* a)
{
    int id;
    int index = -1;

    clear_screen();
    printf("Eliminar contacto\n\n");

    //
    // Pedir id
    //
    printf("Id del contacto que desea eliminar: ");
    id = leer_int();

    //
    // Buscar índice del contacto
    //
    for(int i = 0; i < a->total && index == -1; i++)
    {
        if(a->registros[i].id == id)
        {
            index = i;
        }
    }

    if(index == -1)
    {
        //
        // Si no se encontró el contacto, informar
        //
        printf("No existe el contacto con el id %d\n", id);
    }
    else
    {
        //
        // Si se encontró el contacto, marcarlo como eliminado usando el -1 como id inválido
        //
        a->registros[index].id = -1;

        printf("El contacto ha sido eliminado correctamente\n");
    }
    esperar_enter();
}
void agenda_listar(struct agenda* a)
{
    clear_screen();
    printf("Listado de la agenda:\n\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < a->total; i++)
    {
        if(a->registros[i].id != -1)
        {
            printf("Registro %d\n", i+1);
            printf("  Id: %d\n", a->registros[i].id);
            printf("  Nombre: %s\n", a->registros[i].cto_nom);
            printf("  Telefono: %s\n", a->registros[i].cto_tel);
        }
    }
    esperar_enter();
}

int main()
{
    int opcion;
    struct agenda a;

    //
    // Cargar agenda
    //
    if(!agenda_cargar(&a))
    {
        // Si no se pudo cargar, la agenda no existe, crear una nueva
        agenda_nueva(&a);
    }

    do
    {
        //
        // Listar info y opciones
        //
        clear_screen();
        printf("Total de registros %i\n", a.total);
        printf("  0. Salir. \n");
        printf("  1. Agregar contacto.\n");
        printf("  2. Ver contacto.\n");
        printf("  3. Busqueda\n");
        printf("  4. Eliminar contactos\n");
        printf("  5. Listar todo\n");

        //
        // Ingresar acción
        //
        printf("Ingrese su opcion: ");
        opcion = leer_int();

        switch(opcion)
        {
            case 1:
                agenda_alta(&a);
                break;
            case 2:
                agenda_ver(&a);
                break;
            case 3:
                agenda_busqueda(&a);
                break;
            case 4:
                agenda_eliminar(&a);
                break;
            case 5:
                agenda_listar(&a);
                break;
            default:
                printf("opcion incorrecta\n");
                break;
        }
    }
    while(opcion != 0);

    //
    // Guardar agenda
    //
    agenda_guardar(&a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo lo estudiare para ver si puedo implementarlo gracias.